# Marking question as "unfocused" without feedback isn't helpful

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[My question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/548953/289885) was closed as "[unfocused](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)". At the same time it didn't receive any kind of feedback to describe what is unfocused about it.

That's while the question has a specific and focused question right in it: "3. Ideas for how to filter the data to get rid of the dependance between samples? Would using something like an unscentend Kalman filter be a good idea?".
The other data is provided to create a context for it, the previous two (no.1 and no.2) are there just to show that I'm open to the possibility that "I'm holding it wrong" and that my whole approach is incorrect.

Comment: If the purpose of those questions was to provide context, you could have just made a section of your question labeled “context: “, and then it would have been less likely to be closed.

Comment: The very fact that your question is prefaced by "3." already indicates the post asks too much!  Indeed, this is the third item under "my questions."  We need each thread to ask a single clear question.  Otherwise, the discussion grows confused and complex and any voting becomes almost meaningless.  For more guidance, please look at the links under "Ask" in the [help].

Comment: Some role reversal sometimes helps. FIrst, how long do you think it would take someone competent in your field to read and understand your question. Second, how long do you think that someone would spend answering your question and how much would they write. The first question is hard and the second harder still, but they are key. Hoping for lengthy answers sometimes is realistic, but usually not. If your expectation is that people might answer part of your overall questions, then by CV expectations you're asking several questions.

Comment: The complaint about unhelpful feedback is problematic. We can't rewrite your question for you because it is not our job to decide what is central, essential or most important as the core of your question.

Comment: @NickCox of course it's not your job to to write questions for me, but I know that my problem isn't trivial, I've been trying to solve it for good few months now. Now either that means I'm trying to solve a wrong problem, or the problem itself isn't simple. It's rather hard to show that's the case without providing multiple paragraphs of introductory text.

Comment: CV (and the parts of SE I know best) operates quite differently from say a paper reviewer or academic examiner who ideally should explain in detail and constructively what is wrong with some writing and how to improve it. Questions here are candidates that may be closed given sufficient downvotes or moderator action. You know this, but it is a brutal model compared with others. Closure just means a request to rewrite, not an absolute rejection.

Comment: So, you have, I am happy to believe, a very good and very serious series of linked questions. On the face of it, however, the post  is too long and too complicated to fit our format. That is the main point if not the only point.  I too would be disappointed at best if I put that amount of work into a question and it was closed, but sympathy is not a criterion here.

Comment: And that's precisely my problem: I wrote a detailed question, that was closed without a single comment. It would be sufficient to add a "Please single out a question you want solved" as a comment to make my experience *vastly* better and more welcoming.

Comment: So, now the complaint is about tone of reply. I see in your second link the wording "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."  I read that as polite and as positive as possible. It's not saying Go away, Get lost, or anything more extreme.

Comment: @NickCox the problem is the difference between general FAQ entry vs specific case. From my point of view, the question is already asking a single question "How to deal with this problem". It's the difference between inviting solutions at different levels vs asking a very specific question that may actually not solve the problem. I feel like it's a difference in culture between StackOverflow and CrossValidated...

Comment: Well, I am active on Stack Overflow too -- as witness my profile -- and although I answer only questions on one program I look at their Meta too. I see SO as often utterly ruthless in closing questions and CV as more broad-minded about discussion. Sorry your perception is different.

Comment: I've posted a new, singular, question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/549223/289885

Comment: "... that was closed without a single comment. " -- that's not true. The close notice contains a link to the help article which explains what "needs more focus" means

Comment: My read of the quoted language "Would using something like…" is itself unspecific and unfocused. Contrast with "Could a Kalman filter apply to X? Why or why not?" I encourage Hubert Kairo to take the requests for editing and revision (including the close votes) in the spirit that they are intended: can you narrow down your ask? If you have many (narrow) asks, make many questions.

Comment: @Alexis My ask is that I don't know which exact question is worth looking the answer for. It's useless for me to look for door key in the barn when it's under the flower pot, next to the entrance. Now, maybe I'm wrong in thinking that describing all the places _I_ can think of where the key may be is a waste of everybody's time. But that's what  was my experience on pretty much all help forums I interacted with, and for a good reason, as solving a problem with the wrong approach is frustrating to everybody involved.

Comment: @HubertKario None of us know what your exact question is, either. Maybe take all the feedback you have been given here in good faith and run with it? Maybe a stackexchange does not work for your needs?

Comment: @Alexis I'm not saying it's in bad faith, I'm saying that it's not helpful. Yes, maybe when data acquisition is hard and you can't change the experiment, and you have to work with the data you have, asking for help with the specific data set is your only option. But it's not the case for me, it's definitely not the case for some other people, and "designing experiments" *is* in scope for this site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic